# Spring Data Rest: CORS broken when overriding endpoint with BasePathAwareController

Tags: cors, spring-data-rest

I am trying to use SDR to expose a domain entity but need to implement special behavior for a `PATCH` call. I extends `CrudRepository` and place `@CrossOrigin` on the interface level. With only that, CORS works fine for all endpoints.

```
GET    /invitations       ==> 200
POST   /invitations       ==> 200
GET    /invitations/ID    ==> 200
PATCH  /invitations/ID    ==> 200
DELETE /invitations/ID    ==> 200
```

When I add a class with `@BasePathAwareController` and method with a `@RequestMapping` for that `PATCH` operation, CORS goes down the drain:

```
GET    /invitations       ==> 200
POST   /invitations       ==> 200
GET    /invitations/ID    ==> 403
PATCH  /invitations/ID    ==> 403
DELETE /invitations/ID    ==> 403
```

**InvitationRepo:**
I wasn't sure whether the many annotations make any difference, so I though I'd post the entire interface.

```
@CrossOrigin
public interface InvitationRepo extends CrudRepository<Invitation, UUID> {

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasAnyScopeFor('invitation', 'read')")
    @Query("SELECT e FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE CONCAT(e.tenant.id, '') IN ?#{security.getTenants('invitation', 'r')} OR '*' IN ?#{security.getTenants('invitation', 'r')}")
    @Override
    Iterable<Invitation> findAll();

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasAnyScopeFor('invitation', 'read')")
    @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read')")
    @Override
    Optional<Invitation> findById(UUID id);

    // @formatter:off
    @PreAuthorize(
    "isFullyAuthenticated() and " +
    "(" +
        "(#entity.id == null and (hasPermission(#entity, 'create') or getTenants('invitation', 'create').contains('*')))" +
    ")")
    // @formatter:on
    @Override
    <S extends Invitation> S save(@Param("entity") S entity);

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#entity, 'delete')")
    @Override
    void delete(@Param("entity") Invitation entity);

}
```

InvitationController:

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class InvitationController {

    ...

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() && getActiveTenant() == null")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH, path = "invitations/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> accept(Authentication auth, @PathVariable UUID id) {
        ...
    }

}
```

When I add `@CrossOrigin` at the top of `InvitationController`, the CORS behavior becomes:

```
GET    /invitations       ==> 200
POST   /invitations       ==> 200
GET    /invitations/ID    ==> 403
PATCH  /invitations/ID    ==> 200
DELETE /invitations/ID    ==> 403
```

It looks like it recognizes the `PATCH` endpoint in the controller, but for some reason it still breaks `GET` and `DELETE`. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping` rather than `@BasePathAwareController` on `InvitationController`

Comment: It didn't work with `@RestController` but `@RepositoryRestController` did the job :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

Annotating `InvitationController` with `@RepositoryRestController` did the trick.